# Choosing a better parallel architecture in Python

Tags: parallel-processing, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I am working on Data Wrangling problem using Python, 
which processes a dirty Excel file into a  clean Excel file

I would like to process multiple input files by introducing concurrency/parallelism.

I have the following options 1) Using multiThreading 2) Using multiProceesing modules 3) ParallelPython module,

I have a basic idea of the three methods, I would like to know which method is best and why?

In Bref, Processing of a SINGLE dirty Excel file today takes 3 minutes,

Objective : To introduce parallelism/concurrency to process multiple files at once. 
Looking for, best method of parallelism to achieve the objective

Answer (score 0):

Since your process is mostly CPU bound multi-threading won't be fast because of the GIL...

I would recommend **multiprocessing** or **concurrent.futures** since they are a bit simpler the ParallelPython  (only a bit :) )

example:

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for file_path, clean_file in zip(files, executor.map(data_wrangler, files)):
        print('%s is now clean!' % (file_path))
        #do something with clean_file  if you want
```

Only if you need to distribute the load between servers then I would recommend ParallelPython .